# Megahal eggdrop undefined symbol: PL_thr_key

Tags: compiling, tcl

I recently installed megahal on my eggdrop v1.6.21 and I get this error when I run it

```
Can't load modules Megahal: /home/ubuntu/eggdrop/modules/Megahal.so: undefined symbol: PL_thr_key
```

I compiled the eggdrop with the megahal files, I tried to compile the mehagal separately but the .so file still does not load on startup.

I don't know why this is happening, the eggdrop work's well but how do I make the module to work ?

recently i found this link on google, but i don't know how to apply this method (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1008893)